# If I had been you, I woudn't have gone there. Is this correct sentence?

Tags: grammar

> If I had been you, I woudn't have gone there.

Is this correct sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If I *were* you" is a common idiom. It puts you in somebody else's place, hypothetically.

"If I had been you" is not an idiom. If you think about it, it doesn't really make sense. Even though "if I were you" is purely hypothetical (you can never *really* be someone else) it is at least based on a common premise, how you would behave in the same circumstance. But the tense of "if I *had been* you" sounds like you could have temporarily been that person, and then returned to being yourself.

You don't need to change the tense of "if I were you", because hypotheticals are always *subjunctive*, so it would be fine to say:

> If I were you, I would not have gone there.

Comment: But it's OK to say "If I had been in your shoes..."

Comment: Thx. If we live in the world of being capable of changing ourselves into someone elses by the help of a certain technology, couldn't we say "If I had been you"?

Comment: Such technology would require a revision of language, and notions of identity, since at present "I" and "you" are mutually exclusive. The best you can do is the subjunctive "If I were you".

Comment: @Brandon not if your statement were hypothetical. What is possible doesn't have a bearing on the subjunctive tense of a hypothetical statement.